# Change parent class method behavior, based on extended class (static)

Tags: php

I have a static class that includes various private functions. These are called by a public function. I would like to allow the option of changing one of the private functions. Either using an extended class or in some other way.

Here's my current attempt which isn't working but hopefully demonstrates what I'm trying to achieve.

```
class OriginalClass {

    public static function go()
    {
        self::doThis();
        self::doThat();
        self::doOther();
    }

    private static function doThis()
    {
        echo 'this' . PHP_EOL;
    }

    private static function doThat()
    {
        echo 'that' . PHP_EOL;
    }

    private static function doOther()
    {
        echo 'default' . PHP_EOL;
    } 
}

class ExtendedClass extends OriginalClass {

    private static function doOther()
    {
        echo 'other' . PHP_EOL;
    } 
}

ExtendedClass::go();
```

What I would like to get is

```
this
that
other
```

but I'm getting

```
this
that
default
```

I want `OriginalClass` to be able to be used as is, but I would like to give the option of being able to change what `doOther()` does. I don't mind how, I'm just trying to keep the code clean and not do anything hacky.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`doOther` is a **private** method in both classes. And private methods are **not accessible** anywhere except class, where they are defined.

So `doOther` of `ExtendedClass` context is not accessible from `OriginalClass` context. That's why `go` method can't access `ExtendedClass::doOther`, so it search for `doOther` in a `OriginalClass` which exists.

So, what changes should be done:

1. `ExtendedClass::doOther` should be at least `protected` to be availble in `OriginalClass` context.
2. `self` keyword refers to class `OriginalClass`, use [late static binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) to get the name of a real class which calls for method

---

```
class OriginalClass {

    public static function go()
    {
        self::doThis();
        self::doThat();
        static::doOther();  // keyword `static`
    }

    private static function doThis()
    {
        echo 'this' . PHP_EOL;
    }

    private static function doThat()
    {
        echo 'that' . PHP_EOL;
    }

    private static function doOther()
    {
        echo 'default' . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

class ExtendedClass extends OriginalClass {

    protected static function doOther() // `protected` visiblity
    {
        echo 'other' . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

ExtendedClass::go();
// output:
// this
// that
// other

OriginalClass::go();
// this
// that
// default
```